# Override jquery function

Tags: jquery

This is the original code from a plugin

```
$('body').on('click.eddAddToCart', '.edd-add-to-cart', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this), form = $this.closest('form');

        var variable_price = $this.data('variable-price');
        var price_mode     = $this.data('price-mode');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            ......
            success: function (response) {
                if( edd_scripts.redirect_to_checkout == '1' && form.find( '#edd_redirect_to_checkout' ).val() == '1' ) {

                    window.location = edd_scripts.checkout_page;

                } else {

                    if( variable_price == 'no' || price_mode != 'multi' ) {
                        // Switch purchase to checkout if a single price item or variable priced with radio buttons
                        $('a.edd-add-to-cart', container).toggle();
                        $('.edd_go_to_checkout', container).css('display', 'inline-block');
                    }

                }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to override

```
$('.edd_go_to_checkout', container).css('display', 'inline-block');
```

with

```
$('.edd_go_to_checkout').removeAttr('style').css('display', 'block');
```

Is there an easier way other then copying the entire ajax code into this

```
$("body").off(".eddAddToCart",".edd-add-to-cart").on("click.eddAddToCart",".edd-add-to-cart",function(e){ 
....
});
```

I'm unable to change this with css alone. This is a *checkout* button that shows only after a product has been added.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just hook the line `$('.edd_go_to_checkout').removeAttr('style').css('display', 'block');` to `document.ready`

Comment: If I do that the _checkout_ button shows up before a product is added inside the basket, so two buttons are visible (checkout and add to cart).

Comment: Modify the original code would be my recommendation here. Just my opinion but if this IS a plugin it might be better to re-write it what with those specific classes and ids in it and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is indeed to redefine the plug-in code you quoted. There is no nice way to hook into that plug-in.

Some of the not-so-nice ways to hook are:

1. Redefine the jQuery `$.fn.css` method, so that it first calls the original jQuery `css` method, but then checks whether the current call concerns the call made setting the `inline-block` display style for your specific element: if so, you apply immediately the correction:

   ```
   var orig_fn_css = $.fn.css;
   $.fn.css = function () {
       orig_fn_css.apply(this, arguments);
       if (arguments.length == 2 && arguments[0] == 'display' && arguments[1] == 'inline-block') {
           $(this).filter('.edd_go_to_checkout').removeAttr('style').css('display', 'block');
       }
       return this;
   }
   ```
2. You could use a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect any attribute changes on the target element(s). When triggered, you check whether it concerns the specific `inline-block` display style change, and correct the action:

   ```
   var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
     mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
       if (mutation.attributeName == 'style' && mutation.target.style.display == 'inline-block') {
         // Correct wrong assignment of the 'inline-block' display style:
         $('.edd_go_to_checkout').removeAttr('style').css('display', 'block');
       }
     });    
   });

   $('.edd_go_to_checkout').each(function () {
       observer.observe(this, { attributes: true })
   });
   ```

Neither of these methods is recommendable, mainly because the code becomes harder to understand.

Comment: Went for the second solution `MutationObserver` since that one didn't cause a conflict with another piece of code. Will also look more into these solutions as to why they aren't recommended. Thank you! :)